# Uncaught reference error: JSZip is not defined

Tags: javascript, jszip

I am trying to use JSZip to create a zip file to download through javascript on the client side. I have a function in my script tags that uses `var zip = new JSZip();` - but I get "Uncaught reference error: JSZip is not defined".

I have tried downloading the repository at https://github.com/Stuk/jszip as a zip file into the same directory, and after I used extract all on it, I included `src="jszip-master/jszip-master/dist/jszip.js"` in my script tags to include the jszip file, but when I do this I get an error message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Edit: 
I've tried both `src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.3.0/jszip.min.js"` and `src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.3.0/jszip.js"` inside the script tags, but when I do this I get a new error that says "Uncaught reference error: myFunction is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick - this does not happen if I exclude the src attributes, in which case the function starts but JSZip isn't recognised.

If I include this src attribute with either of the cdns in script tags outside of the one that contains the function, then I still get the same "Uncaught reference error: JSZip is not defined" error

Comment: You might not be serving the `jszip-master` directory on your local server. If I were you, I'd just use the CDN, but if you insist, you should ensure that you're hosting the `jszip-master` directory relative to your HTML file. Oh, and the path is almost certainly supposed to be `jszip-master/dist/jszip.js`.

Comment: I've tried both src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.3.0/jszip.min.js" and src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.3.0/jszip.js" inside the script tags, but when I do this I get a new error that says "Uncaught reference error: myFunction is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick - this does not happen if I exclude the src attributes, in which case the function starts but JSZip isn't recognised

Comment: That would be a bug in your code. There's no such thing as `myFunction` in JSZip. Try an empty HTML file with just a JSZip script, and you'll see that it works and you can use JSZip from the developer console. Also, you need to have `src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.3.0/jszip.min.js"` or it will look like a relative path.

Comment: I have a button that has onclick="myFunction()", and this function has the var zip = new JSZip(); line - but even when I include the cdn in separate script tags it says "Uncaught reference error: JSZip is not defined" -> I have confirmed that myFunction is started by having console.log statements

Comment: Have you tried using the `https://` prefix? That's necessary to prevent it from looking like a relative path.

Comment: turns out I need the JSZip Utils library which is completely different from jszip - I'm not getting the error now